# Lightning Component Action failed:lightning:recordViewForm Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've got a pretty basic lightning component that pulls some Account information for accounts related to a Case. This component sits in Service Console.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">


<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="Account" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="Case" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" />


<force:recordData aura:id="record"
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            targetError="{!v.recordError}"
            targetRecord="{v.record}"
            targetFields="{!v.Case}"
            layoutType="FULL"
            mode="VIEW"
            />



<lightning:card iconName="standard:account" title="Account Details" >
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.Case.AccountId}" objectApiName="Account">
            <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="BillingStreet" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="BillingCity" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="BillingState" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Phone" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Customer_Type__c" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Seek_And_Find_Widget_Deployed__c" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Seek_And_Find_Widget_Deployed_Dt__c" />
            </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</lightning:card> 
</aura:component>
```

When the page loads, it's throwing the following error:

> Action failed:
>   lightning:recordViewForm$controller$handleRecordIdChange [Cannot read
>   property 'getList' of null]

Component Descriptor

> markup://lightning:recordViewForm

Function:

> Object.getFields

There is an account related to the case and it does actually pull in the correct data. But it's throwing this error every time. When I remove that specific component from the page, the error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component implements [`force:RecordId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation), and that you also have the `recordId` attribute declared as `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />`.

From the documentation of [`force:RecordId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation), refer to the excerpt (emphasis mine):

> Note If your component implements `force:hasRecordId`, **you don’t need to add** a `recordId` attribute to the component yourself. **If you do add it, don’t change the access level or type** of the attribute or the component will cause a runtime error.

In your case, because the `recordId` attribute's type is that of `Id`, it is causing a runtime error as mentioned in the documentation.

For your component to work correctly, follow one of the below steps:

- Remove the `recordId` attribute declaration from your component

  OR
- Change the type of the `recordId` attribute to `String` as `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />`

Comment: I tried both of these changes and it's still throwing the error.

Comment: I can confirm this that I was able to replicate the error, and then following this approach it was resolved. You may like to make the change, clear the cached contents and then try it out.

Comment: Yep. Was just going to comment and say I think it's a caching issue. Thanks!